# Fisheye distortion of MovieClip (AS3)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, visualization, fisheye, distortion

Some pseudo-code for accomplishing a **linear fisheye distortion** of a MovieClip's contents would be very appreciated.

The attached illustration shows how the "fisheye effect" is automatically applied to an area around the mouse-pointer.

The Flare toolkit has examples of both Bifocal and Fisheye distortion [here](http://flare.prefuse.org/demo).

[distorted movieclip http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/10925464bd.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/10925464bd.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`DisplacementMapFilter`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/filters/DisplacementMapFilter.html) can be used to do this.

```
DisplacementMapFilter(bmp,offset,1,2,75,75,"ignore")
```

Will give pleasing results.